# Is it possible to join many to many and one to many in one go?

Tags: mysql, join

My tables have the following schema:
wp_careers
[image]

wp_locations
[image]

wp_careers_locations
[image]

wp_educations
[image]

A career applicant can apply to many locations, and have many educational records.

The desired result is to get ALL records from wp_careers and group the applied locations as a locations fields, and put all educational records (wp_educations) as an array attached to the applicant.

Right now I know how to join many to many relations and group the locations:

```
  SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(l.name) as locations
  FROM wp_careers c
  JOIN wp_careers_locations cl ON c.id = cl.career_id
  JOIN wp_locations l ON cl.location_id = l.id
  GROUP BY c.id
```

But I don't know how to extend this query to include the educational records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to just join again:

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.name) as locations,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.institute) AS edu_institutes
FROM wp_careers c
LEFT JOIN wp_careers_locations cl ON c.id = cl.career_id
LEFT JOIN wp_locations l ON cl.location_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN wp_educations e ON c.id = e.career_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

But this is likely to create a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), as it will inadvertently join every location to every education. So if you have three locations and two educations for a given career, it will generate 3x2 = 6 rows when you didn't expect it to. I tried to compensate for this with `DISTINCT` so the list of names in each GROUP_CONCAT() will eliminate duplicates.

But honestly, I would prefer to run two queries. One for locations, and a second query for educations. That would avoid the Cartesian product. MySQL is not so weak that it can't handle an extra query, and it might actually be less expensive than doing the DISTINCT operations.

---

Re your comment:

You want to restrict careers in the education query only to those that have at least one location?

You can do this with a semi-join:

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(e.institute) AS edu_institutes
FROM wp_careers c
JOIN wp_educations e ON c.id = e.career_id
WHERE c.id IN (SELECT career_id FROM wp_career_locations)
GROUP BY c.id
```

Even though there may be multiple rows in wp_career_locations matching each respective c.id, it doesn't cause a Cartesian product.

Comment: To run 2 queries, how do I get only the wp_educations records that match the career ids I have. For example if 15 records are retrieved from wp_careers based on some conditions like LIMIT 15, I only want the wp_educations records related to the wp_careers being retreived.